# useState in onclick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Here's the UI

[image]

Where I click the first button, then click the second button, it shows value 1, but I expect it to show value 2, since I set the value to 2. What's the problem and how should I address that?

Here's the code:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useCallback
} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(channel);
  }, [channel]);
  
  const parentClick = () => {
    console.log("parent is call");
    setChannel(2);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setChannel(1);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={parentClick}>Click to SetChannel 2</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to ShowChannel 2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ellis-g3rfi6?file=/src/index.js:0-773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChannel(1);
  });
```

Runs on every render, so it's always reverting back to 1

Comment: This is the problem, sure, but the question also asks how to address it.

Comment: add dependency to your useEffect, the first argument of useEffect is function and second is array of dependency.

Comment: I'm on my phone, so dont have capacity for an in-depth answer. And to be honest it's not clear what the desired functionality is, by either reading the question or looking at the attempt

Answer (score 2):

Add a dependency to the `useEffect` hook, if you don't add any dependency it will just re-run on every state change.

Change this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setChannel(1);
  });
```

To this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setChannel(1);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are setting channel value to 1 every render.
You have 2 options.

- Set initial state value of channel to 1 (see below)
- Call `this.setState({channel: 1})` in the `componentDidMount` method.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {channel: 1};
    }

    handleClick=(evt)=> {
        console.log(this.state.channel);
    }

    parentClick=(evt)=> {
        this.setState({channel: 2});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={this.parentClick}>Click to SetChannel 2</button>
                <br /><br />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to ShowChannel 2</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

PS: It's not clear what you're trying to do & your sandbox is quite different from the code you have posted here.